# xpath to evaluate multiple element values

Tags: javascript, java, xml, xpath, xquery

I have an XML as below:

```
<Accounts>
   <Account>
    <AccountNumber>12345</AccountNumber>
    <Status>NEW</Status>
   </Account>
   <Account>
    <AccountNumber>12346</AccountNumber>
    <Status>NEW</Status>
  </Account>
  <Account>
   <AccountNumber>12347</AccountNumber>
   <Status>NEW</Status>
 </Account>
</Accounts>
```

I need an xpath to check if all the element value of 'Status' is 'NEW', then xpath expression has to return back true, else it has to return false.

I have written an xpath '//*/Status/text() = 'NEW'' to achieve it. But this is returning true always even if the value of "Status" is other than 'NEW'.

Answer (score 2):

Your XPath,

```
//*/Status/text() = 'NEW''
```

fails because it's testing for existence, not universality.

Instead, use one of the following, depending upon the particulars of your requirements:

- All `Account`s must have a `Status` and it must be `<Status>NEW</Status>`:

  ```
  not(//Account[not(Status='NEW')])
  ```
- Any `Account`s that have a `Status` must have it be `<Status>NEW</Status>`:

  ```
  not(//Account[Status!='NEW'])
  ```

Answer (score 0):

It might be enough to check, if there is any `<Status>` where the `text()` is **not equal** to "NEW". Something like this:

```
/Accounts/Account[Status/text()!="NEW"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `not(//Status[. != 'NEW''])`